# MySQL workbench max of a count

Tags: mysql, count, max

As an SQL goofball, I am completely flummoxed by trying to do a 2 column count max.

I have a database of transactions and I want to get the highest frequency recipient for each user.

Data is:

```
User  Recipient 
 A        B
 A        C
 A        B
 A        F
 D        A
 D        C
 D        A
 D        A
```

Desired result is

```
User Recipient Count
 A      B       2
 D      A       3
```

I manage to get the count but I can't seem to get the max recipient out.

I've tried using an inner join, and a where statement, but it failed to work.

In case of ties, it doesn't matter which value is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the maximum in MySQL is a bit of a pain.  Here is one method:

```
select user, recipient, count(*)
from t
group by user, recipient
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.user = t.user
                   group by user, recipient
                   order by count(*) desc
                   limit 1
                  );
```

Note:  This version will return duplicates when there are ties.  If you don't want duplicates, you can instead do:

```
select user, recipient, count(*)
from t
group by user, recipient
having recipient = (select recipient
                    from t t2
                    where t2.user = t.user
                    group by user, recipient
                    order by count(*) desc
                    limit 1
                   );
```